# how to request form data data nil?

Tags: swift, multipartform-data, form-data

i want to request form data for image data.
Implementing profile changes If I send a false value, the server will judge it and keep the profile image unchanged. Then how can I send a false value to the form data? When I look it up, nil is not included in the form data.

```
if img != nil {
            multipartFormData.append(img!, withName: "img", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }else {
            multipartFormData.append(nil, withName: "img", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    if img != nil {
      multipartFormData.append(img!, withName: "img", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
    } else {
      multipartFormData.append(Data(), withName: "img", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
   }
```